# Can you tell me how to make use of XQuery here?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

```
let $db := xdmp:databases()[1]
let $db-name := xdmp:database-name($db)
let $db-forests := xdmp:database-forests($db, fn:false())
let $forests-name := xdmp:forest-name($db-forests) 
let $forests-name := for $f in xdmp:forest-name($db-forests) 
                        order by $f ascending
                      return $f
let $forest-status := xdmp:forest-status($db-forests)
let $map := map:map()
let $_ := for $f in $forests-name
            let $host-id := $forest-status/f:host-id/text() where ($forest-status/f:forest-name[. = $f] and ($forest-status/f:availablility/text() eq "online"))
            let $_ := if(map:contains(xdmp:host-name($host-id))) then() else()
          return $host-id
return $forest-status
```

I am getting error as I'm not using Xquery correctly. Please guide me.

Comment: Perhaps you could share the error you are getting....

Comment: And also elaborate on what you are trying to do.. :)

Comment: I'm getting this error - 1.0-ml] XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected Let_, expecting Order_ or Return_ or Stable_
and updated the code for better understanding

Comment: Is there a problem in using 'where' and 'and' ?

Comment: the problem might be in your last FLWR, where you use an additional `let` after using a `where` and before reaching the `return`. It seems unused, so I'd just remove it (the `let $_`)

Comment: We can't be expected to reverse-engineer your requirements from a query that doesn't meet them. Tell us what's in the input, tell us what you want in the output, and tell us how your current attempt fails.

Answer (score 3):

1. A FLWOR statement is not just the name - it is the order in which things need to be done.  you have let-where-let in your FLWOR statement. Re-arrange it. It is upset about the second let statement because it comes after the where statement..
2. Second - from a visual inspection, you seem to have no namespace binding for the prefix 'f'.
3. Third - a visual inspection suggests that your map statement will fail because:

   - 1 the map never seems to have values
   - 2 the map:contains function does not have enough parameters..